# How to create disabled state of the font awesome icons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am using font awesome icons and I need to have a disabled state of the icons. is there any way to do this. I am also using bootstrap.

This is how I am using icons.

```
<i class="fa fa-slack"><i/>
```

I just need the icon to look like grayed out.

Answer (score 36):

Write a custom class for disabled

Something like

```
.fa-disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Adding cursor type is important for users experience.

Comment: thanks, inspired by this answer I came up with this style: .fa[disabled] { opacity: 0.65;  cursor: default; } . opacity: 0.65 -> bootstrap default opacity, cursor: default -> bootstrap default disabled button cursor

Answer (score 19):

You could define your "Bootstrap-like" `disabled` class

```
.fa.disabled,
.fa[disabled],
.disabled > .fa,
[disabled] > .fa {
  opacity: 0.5;
  /*optional*/ cursor: not-allowed;
  /*optional*/ pointer-events: none;
}
```

and then use it like

```
<i class="fa fa-slack disabled"></i> <!-- or -->
<i class="fa fa-slack" disabled></i> <!-- or -->
<a class="btn btn-primary disabled"><i class="fa fa-slack"></i></a> <!-- or -->
<a class="btn btn-primary" disabled><i class="fa fa-slack"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 6):

The basic idea is just to color its style

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>Disabled <i class="fa fa-slack" style="color: grey"></i></div>
<div>Enabled <i class="fa fa-slack"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can decrease the opacity and disable the pointer events:

```
.disabled-button{
      opacity: 0.5;
      pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Comment: This is perfect, it disables any click events

Comment: This is also disabling the tooltip on the icon, how to enable the tooltip (which we give through title="")

Answer (score 0):

`$("button[title='Aceptar']").prop("disabled", true);` where you can select the button by any of its property (first) and change property disabled.