# enable disable font-awesome icon

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have down arrow font-awesome icone. I try to disable the icon for some validation reason . But when i given a option 'disable' , it is not working.

```html
<div class="arrow bounce text-center" >
     <div class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-3x " style="padding-bottom: 2px;" disabled="disabled"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.arrow {
    text-align: center;
    margin:40px 0px;
}
.bounce {
    -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%,
    20%,
    30%,
    40%,
    50% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    30% {
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
}
```

what is wrong in my code here ?

Comment: What does `disabled` to the the div? It's an attribute for an `input` not a div. **Also**, divs don't have `href`s. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to disable the font icon. So used disabled property. but it is not working.

Comment: It wouldn't, it's not an attribute that applies to divs. Plus your HTML & CSS don't match.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled

Comment: It seems that you've left out some information/code. You have CSS animations but don't see them being applied to your HTML. How is this being accomplished?

Comment: @hungerstar:- i have updated my code .

Comment: I take it the icon should **not bounce** when disabled?

Comment: @hungerstar :- Yes, icon should not  bounce when it is disable. Incase , disable will work only for input attributes, is there any other way can do this.?

Comment: Also I'm not 100% sure that `href` is an attribute that should be on a div - but to be fair I actually haven't read through the HTML5 specs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781104/how-to-create-disabled-state-of-the-font-awesome-icons

Answer (score 0):

The problem is tha disabled attribute is for input, button or anchor elements. You are trying to set "disabled" in a div.
Just change:

```
<div class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-3x custom-color" href="#" style="padding-bottom: 2px;" disabled="disabled"></div>
```

with:

```
<a class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-3x custom-color" href="#" style="padding-bottom: 2px;" disabled="disabled"></a>
```

**Edit:**

My bad. Disabled attr is not for anchor. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711317/is-disabled-a-valid-attribute-for-an-anchor-tag).
The only way to prevent the anchor to be clicked is via JavaScript. But this issue you have is not related with the font-awesome icons

Comment: is there any attribute to disable the icon.

Comment: I tried with <a> also instead of <div>. Still it is not working.

Comment: but you want a div to be disabled for doing what? a div is not a "clickable" element. Do not force it.

Comment: Okay. but <a> also not able to disabled with 'disabled' option. is there any other solution ?

Comment: I edited the answer. It seems that anchor does not allow disabled attr. Only button and input do.

Comment: `disabled` works with form inputs, i.e. `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Working but non W3C conform:

```
.fa[disabled] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

However the "disabled" attribute isn't W3C compatible with the ["div" tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp), you have to use a CSS class instead and toggle it with JavaScript when disabled or not.

Here is an exemple :

```css
.fa.disabled {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button onclick="$('#AppleLogo').toggleClass('disabled');">Pop/unpop Apple</button>
<br/>
<i id="AppleLogo" class="fa fa-apple fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Diverse solutions :

- **display: none !important;** and **font-size: 0px !important;** makes the same render. The element seems not rendered from the page. The !important is important in that case to be superior to FontAwesome classes.
- **visibility: hidden;** is a bit different because the element is still rendered, but it is transparent. **color: transparent !important;** will also work the same in that case. It keeps it same place and space.

Optional: FontAwesome is made to be used in "i" tag as described in the [documentation](http://fontawesome.io/examples/)

Comment: The `disabled` attribute and the elements it works with has already been tackled by comments to the OP's question and answers to it. FontAwesome uses the `<i>` but is not required, it is an inline element like many others. I suggest you update your answer to your suggestion of  toggling a CSS class.

Comment: Hi !
I updated my comment, by adding a snippet and explaining the diverse solutions. I was just explaining him how he should code, not providing the copy-paste solution.
I know for the `<i>` ... just showing for better usage.
I hope you will enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Code for VueJS:
with html:

```
<div class="arrow bounce text-center" >
 <div class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-3x " style="padding-bottom: 2px;" v-bind:style="disabled ? 'color: #b7b7b7' : '' " @click="toDoFunc()">
```

with js, please check it to disable I tag

```
toDoFunc: function() {
  if (!disabled ) {
   //to do if condition true
  }
},
```